# c# File.WriteAllBytes doesn't work / Filepath doesn't work

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, byte, filepath

I wanted to download an assembly and save it into the Managed Folder of the Unity Game.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("file:///" + Application.dataPath + "/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll", assembly.bytes);
```

But somehow it doesn't download it..
It only downloads when I just use ("Assembly-CSharp.dll");

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Assembly-CSharp.dll", assembly.bytes);
```

Fast help needed!

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Also mention the platform you are running this code on

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Comment: Your edit did not improve anything. It doesn't answer the platform you are running this code on...iOS? Android? Windows? Also, it doesn't explain your "does not work" issue. Do you see any error? The error message can help so much. Also, you talked about downloading not working. All I see is save not download code....

Comment: Oh, yes it's windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax. Fix your filepath:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("file:///"...
```

You can either provide a full path to the file, e.g.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/myFile.txt", assembly.bytes);
```

Or navigate to the file from you Unity's main folder, just like you did in your second code.

Possible, alterative solution if you're on Mac/iOS:

> If it was on iOS on the Mac, it could be defaulted to WebPlayer on the transition as you can't set an iOS build target on PC.
>
> Solution: Set your target to one of Standalone PC when on PC.

[source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/writeallbytes-missing.103436/)

Comment: I marked it and I navigated from Unity's main folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just two cents, Pitor's answers is the right answer.

But as a better practice you should use `Path.Combine`

In your case:

```
var fileName = "/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll";
var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, assembly.bytes);
```

And you don't have to deal with platform dependent code.